# Maintain hover state on parent of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I need to on hovering dropdown menu "elements 1 2 3" keep "parent 2" element orange with black font.

Here is my code:

```
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 2px;
    /* bypass error */
}

#cssmenu > ul li a.active, #cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
    background: #FFAB22;
    color: black;
}

#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #442AB0;
    color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uf60vpja/

I tried this solutions from stackoverflow, but without a success:

[How to keep list item in active state whilst hovering on dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789754/how-to-keep-list-item-in-active-state-whilst-hovering-on-dropdown)

[Maintain 'hover' state on parent of dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338378/maintain-hover-state-on-parent-of-dropdown)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: apply the hover state to the parent, not the `a`. http://jsfiddle.net/uf60vpja/1/ All I did was change `li a:hover` to `li:hover a`

Comment: but the orange background is also aplied to a dropdown elements which should be white

Comment: Thanks, adding #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li a {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
} solved the problem